# Cannot set a click listener for the button that is first outside of the screen (and then animates inside)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to recreate the edit behavior of iOS list in Android using a RecyclerView. This is the result I want to get (without the delete button):

[image: iOS edit mode]

I don't need the edit button in this context and I am assuming that the little red circle on the left side is always there. When you click the red round button, a rectangle delete button should slide from the right, pushing the row to the left.

What I tried to do was to have a horizontal `LinearLayout` that is hosting two children. One is a `ConstraintLayout` that has the main layout of each row and its width is set to `match_parent` so that it take all the screen width. The other child is the delete button with the width of `130dp` which will be outside the screen by default.

Here's the code to the layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/remove_circle_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove_circle"
                android:background="@null"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/remove_circle_button"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="some text" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_main_button"
            style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My logic is that when the user clicks the circular red button, the linear layout will animate `130dp` to the left making the red button visible while the rest of the row is pushed to the left. Visually it looks good enough for the requirement we have.

Here's the code to the RecyclerView adapter that I wrote:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mStrings;
    private SparseBooleanArray mHasDeleteButtonPressed;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mStrings = strings;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String value = mStrings.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(value);
        holder.smallDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.rootLayout.animate().translationX(
                        -1 * holder.mainDeleteButton.getWidth())
                        .setDuration(300)
                        .start();
                mHasDeleteButtonPressed.put(holder.getAdapterPosition(), false);
            }
        });

        holder.mainDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mStrings.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout rootLayout;
        TextView textView;
        ImageButton smallDeleteButton;
        Button mainDeleteButton;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rootLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
            smallDeleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_circle_button);
            mainDeleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_main_button);
        }
    }
}
```

The boolean array is to know which button of each row was clicked so that we can animate back the delete button if the user decided they didn't want to delete that row.

Theoretically, with this code the delete button should be pressed and a toast should be shown stating that the button was clicked. However, it appears that the `OnClickListener` is not being set at all and no code inside the `onClick` method is being called. My suspicion is that since the button is outside the screen at first, and we are forcing the view not to clip it (using `android:clipChildren="false"` in the xml file), the `setOnClickListener` method is not working. Because when I rearrange the layout in a way that the Delete button is inside the screen, the adapter code above will work without any changes.

So how can I fix my problem? I don't want to use any external libraries and I want to do this in a RecyclerView.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you set click listener on delete button after finish animation?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. I can't say what is really going on, but the button that you are sliding onto the screen is being defined outside the bounds of the screen and never really gets onto the screen although it appears to. It's hit rectangle is defined off the screen so the button never gets clicked.

My solution is to first simplify the layout for the `RecyclerView` items as follows:

**activity_main.xml**

I have changed a few things such as the button color, etc. for my own ease of use, but they have no bearing on the solution.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/remove_circle_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/remove_circle_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/remove_main_button"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This layout will show the button on screen. In the activity, the layout will be given a specified width that is the width of the screen plus the width of the button. This re-dimensioning of the layout will move the button off-screen. Code can then do a translation to move it back onto the screen.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private View rootLayout;
    private View mainDeleteButton;
    private View circleButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        mainDeleteButton = findViewById(R.id.remove_main_button);
        circleButton = findViewById(R.id.remove_circle_button);
        rootLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rootLayout.getLayoutParams().width = rootLayout.getWidth() + mainDeleteButton.getWidth();
                rootLayout.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        circleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootLayout.animate().translationX(
                    -1 * mainDeleteButton.getWidth())
                    .setDuration(300)
                    .start();
            }
        });

        mainDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the effect:

[image]

Although this example does not involve a `RecyclerView`, the technique can be applied to a `RecyclerView`.